# Download and process large json file in a firebase cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a large json file (~2GB) that I am storing in a firebase storage bucket and would like to download and process the JSON in a firebase cloud function using Node. Due to the large file size I am attempting to use the `JSONStream` package to stream the file contents. When I deploy the code below to firebase and upload the file the only output I see in the function log is from where I am logging "processing file". It appears that the file downloads successfully as I the function runs for ~90 seconds and I see the 'file downloaded' message in the function logs but as far as I can tell the stream is never created. I am not getting any errors from the catch statement or in the logs, the output just stops after the 'file downloaded' message. I believe the container is cleaning up before the code to create the stream is executed but I am not sure why.

```
 exports.importJSON = onObjectFinalized({ memory: "8GiB", cpu: 2, timeoutSeconds: 3600 }, (event) => {
    logger.info("processing file", { structuredData: true });

    const fileBucket = event.data.bucket; 
    const filePath = event.data.name; 

    var tempFilePath = tmp.tmpNameSync();

    
    const bucket = getStorage().bucket  (fileBucket);

    return bucket.file(filePath).download({ destination: tempFilePath })
    .then(() => {
        logger.log('file downloaded');
        let stream = fs.createReadStream(tempFilePath);
        stream
            .pipe(JSONStream.parse('*'))
            .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
                logger.log(data);
                return database.doc(`/ticketmaster_events/${uuidv4()}`).create({
                    name: data.eventName,
                    date: new Date(Date.parse(data.date)),
                    venue: data.venue.venueName,
                    // venueAddress: data.venueAddress,
                    locale: data.locale
                });
            }))
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        logger.error(error);
    }) 
});
```

Comment: There's a lot that could be going wrong here. A few that jump out straight away: 1) you're not returning a promise, so the asynchronous download operation can be aborted at any time. I recommend reading https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions and watching the videos in there. 2) this function will need at least 2GB of free memory + the size of the ZIP file and any overhead.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the suggestion, I looked over the link and some of those videos and have updated my code. I thought that returning the promise from downloading the file would execute everything in the .then and then return but it seems like the function is stopping after downloading the file.

Comment: Your `then` block isn't returning a promise, so while you *may* be waiting for the `download` itself to finish, you're not waiting for the `stream` to resolve, nor for the database write to finish. Also note #2 in my comment about memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with, my issue was not returning resolving the stream inside of a promise.

```
exports.importJSON = onObjectFinalized({ memory: "16GiB", cpu: 4, timeoutSeconds: 3600 }, (event) => {
    logger.info("processing file", { structuredData: true });

    const fileBucket = event.data.bucket; 
    const filePath = event.data.name; 

    var tempFilePath = tmp.tmpNameSync();

    
    const bucket = getStorage().bucket  (fileBucket);

    return bucket.file(filePath).download({ destination: tempFilePath })
    .then(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            logger.log('file downloaded');
            let events: any[]= [];
            let stream = fs.createReadStream(tempFilePath);
            stream
                .pipe(JSONStream.parse('events.*'))
                .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
                    logger.log(events.length)
                    events.push({
                        name: data.eventName,
                        date: !isNaN(Date.parse(data.eventStartDateTime)) ? new Date(Date.parse(data.eventStartDateTime)) : Date.now(),
                        venue: data.venue.venueName,
                        // venueAddress: data.venueAddress,
                        locale: data.venue.venueCity + ", " + data.venue.venueStateCode
                    })
                }))
                .on('end', () => resolve(events))
            })
        }).then(async (events) => {
            logger.log(`second .then, ${(events as Array<any>).length} events`);
            let collection = admin.firestore().collection('ticketmaster_events');

            let position = 0;
            var results: Array<any> = [];
            let batchSize = 250;
            while (position < events.length) {
                const eventsBatch = events.slice(position, position + batchSize);
                results = [...results, ...await Promise.all(eventsBatch.map(event => collection.add(event)))]
                position += batchSize;
            }
            
            logger.log(`wrote ${results.length} results to db`)
            return results;
        })
});
```

Comment: While creating a Promise does cause the function to not immediately terminate, you don't ever call `resolve` or `reject` to fulfil the Promise.